# Returning a different response object in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to port a proxy feature that is used for debugging purposes from a hapi.js server to an express.js server.

The feature uses the `https` module to retrieve data from a different server and I want to simply forward the response from this retrieval to the original client.

Simplified code:

```
server.get('/proxy/*', (req, res) => {
  https.request({
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: 'example.com',
    path: req.url.replace(/^\/proxy\//, ''),
    headers: Object.assign({}, req.headers)
  }, (proxiedResponse) => {
    // respond with proxiedResponse here somehow
  });
});
```

In Hapi, I could do this easily with `reply(proxiedResponse);` (`reply` is Hapi's counterpart to `res`) since `reply` isn't an actual response object but a function that internally creates and dispatches a response.
Since in Express, `res` is the actual response object I guess I need to replace/mod it somehow.

Is there a way to do this in an easier way than to explicitly copy every relevant piece of data from `proxiedResponse` into `res`?

Comment: That's easier to do using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#streaming).

Comment: @robertklep You mean the `https` part? Sure, but that's not what I'm having a problem with. Or do you mean there's a way to use `request` to handle the response in the Express route?

Comment: The latter. I linked to the relevant part of the documentation, if you scroll down a bit you'll see some examples on how it's really easy to proxy requests (it's basically `req.pipe(request({...})).pipe(res)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use

`res.send(proxiedResponse)`